# ToastContentBuilder - Can not Show Toast Notification since upgraded to .NET 8.0

Tags: c#, wpf

I had a project targeting the .NET 4.7.2 which I have recently upgraded to the new .NET 8.0 using Upgrade Assistant Visual Studio extension.
The upgrade completed successfully.
However I have an issue with the following function which is built to show Toast notification since I perform the upgrade :

```
using Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications;

public static void ShowNotif(string title, string body)
{
    new ToastContentBuilder()
                .AddText(title)
                .AddText(body)
                .AddAppLogoOverride(new Uri(@"D:\Users\XXXXXX\XXXXXX.png"))
                .SetToastDuration(ToastDuration.Long)
                .SetToastScenario(ToastScenario.Reminder)
                .Show();
}
```

The method .Show() is now underlined in red and Visual Studio show the error :

Error   CS1061  'ToastContentBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'Show' and no accessible extension method 'Show' accepting a first argument of type 'ToastContentBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

As a result, the Toast notifications are no longer displayed when I run my application.

I tried to add a new parameter by typing "." to get the available method and .Show() is not displayed. I did not find other method to replace it.

Comment: Most likely you forgot to specify target framework moniker option. [.NET 6 and later: Use the Target Framework Moniker option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-enhance#net-6-and-later-use-the-target-framework-moniker-option)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However this is what I have in my Project File :  <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0-windows</TargetFramework>

Comment: It is not enough as mm8 answered,

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the OS version in your TFM in the project file.

Set your TFM to `net8.0-windows10.0.17763.0` or later:

```
<TargetFramework>net8.0-windows10.0.17763.0</TargetFramework>
```